# call cropUrl in croppic js

Tags: jquery, crop

I'm using this javascript http://www.croppic.net
In the examples when I select an image, some icon appears and one of them is used to call the file that save the image as I cropped it. This file is specified in the options as cropUrl:

```
var croppicContaineroutputMinimal = {
                uploadUrl:'upload_url.php',
                customUploadButtonId:'loadBtn',
                cropUrl:'img_crop_to_file.php', 
                modal:false,
                doubleZoomControls:false,
                rotateControls: false,
                loaderHtml:'<div class="loader bubblingG"><span id="bubblingG_1"></span><span id="bubblingG_2"></span><span id="bubblingG_3"></span></div> '
            }

            var croppic = new Croppic('cropImage', croppicContaineroutputMinimal);
```

How can I do to call this file using a button click and pass al the data that it needs to save the image as i cropped it? In the docs are specified only two methods but nothing about one that can do this action